# How is score calculated?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Okay, so I've managed to beat the game on Normal. It seems like the thing to do now is work on getting a higher score.

However, scoring is a complete mystery to me. What sort of things should I do (or not do) to improve my score?

**Hard numbers, if possible, would be a huge benefit.**

Answer (score 11):

According to the in-game tips,

> Your score is based on how many ships you defeat, the number of beacons explored, and your total scrap collection.

The actual equation is **20 × Ships Defeated + 10 × Beacons Explored + Scrap Collected**.

Comment: It's that simple?  I'm surprised at that.

Comment: No bonus for killing the boss? Also, I wonder if surrenders count as defeats. This may call for Science!

Comment: Science! is how I figured that much out. I didn't beat the boss's final form yet, so not sure. Surrenders should be easy to check though...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the difficulty setting has an influence too, but I have no official source for that.

Comment: It does seem pretty strange that defeating the boss doesn't significantly increase one's score.  I've found that in some games where I won, I got a lower score than in other games that I lost.

Answer (score 4):

Difficulty is a flat bonus, I believe 25%, to offset the equivalent scrap bonus for easy. The precise value IS listed somewhere on the official site if someone wishes to go digging.